# Sending WhatsApp messages with multiple media types in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, whatsapp

I am trying to send both an audio clip and a url in one message via whatsapp.

I am using the following code to send audio:

```
let activityItem = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: “Audio1”, ofType: “mp3")!)
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityItem],applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and this code to send a url:

```
let urlString = "Visit this website: http://www.google.com"
let urlStringEncoded = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
let url  = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(urlStringEncoded)")

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url! as URL) {
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url! as URL)
}
```

I have tried a number of things to send them together but haven't been able to figure it out. Does anybody know if I can send both at once and if so, how would I do it?

Comment: You can not send two different types of data with the same message

Comment: @a.masri is it possible to send audio and some text?

Comment: You can not send audio and text together see this https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013